# Open Wechat official account via link on external page

Tags: html, css, api, protocols, wechat

I couldn't find any reference to that question, and I hope someone here knows.

I created a promotional html5 page for a client. This page is on my server. I am sharing the page address via WeChat to the client, and he is re-sharing it to his friends. When they open the page, it's opening in the WeChat APP Browser.

So far so good.

He asked me to implement a button / link on that page, directing users to his official account on WeChat. And that's where I am stuck, because I couldn't find any reference for doing this, but I know it's possible.

I found some QR codes, that when scanned via the WeChat APP, are opening an official page, inside the WeChat APP. Yet I couldn't find any way via HTML to do this.

Anyone has a suggestion?

PS:

```
weixin://contacts/profile/name
```

is not working for me.

The process in steps:

1. User scans QR code via WeChat APP, gets to landing page (inside WeChat)
2. User clicks on link / button and is being redirected to an "official page/profile" inside WeChat

Thanks a lot!

George

Answer (score 8):

Wechat used to open this function that user can open such url 'weixin://contacts/profile/name' to redirect the official account page. But due to it's mostly abused on illegal marketing, the function is closed. Such url now redirect to app-store to install wechat app.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve it somehow now, if i have a subscription account ?