# How to programatically initialize Follow-a-WeChat-official-account screen in WeChat, from my Android app

Tags: java, android, wechat

I am building an Android app with some 3D experience. At the end of the experience, user will be shown a button to click on to "Follow us on WeChat". When user clicks on it, ideally, I'd like to invoke WeChat app (which I know user will 100% have it installed on his device) and to open the screen to follow my official account.

I've been looking at WeChat Android SDK as well as googling around, but haven't found any straightforward solution that works. There used to be a URL-based instruction (wx:// or weixin://, something like that) but that appears not to work anymore: [Open Wechat official account via link on external page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780506/open-wechat-official-account-via-link-on-external-page)

I've read that WeChat has disabled above option because of mass abuse, and the only way is to initialise "Scan QR code to follow" inside WeChat. Now, I can do this from an HTML5 page that runs inside WeChat, but I'd need to somehow do this from my own Android app.

Basically, I'd have a QR code on my app's screen, and ideally, would somehow on user click / long press, launch WeChat app and pass QR code image to it. Or any other workaround, if this is not possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find any alternatives to that problem? I am facing the same issue. [This page](https://www.zhihu.com/question/30616809?sort=created) has a lot of deep links, but none seems to be able to open a profile page.

Comment: @DannyTran no solution yet, project was cancelled so I stopped researching this issue. Will however post a solution if I find it.