# wechat official account url link?

Tags: url

There's a similar question here:

[Open Wechat official account via link on external page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780506/open-wechat-official-account-via-link-on-external-page)

answer from almost three years ago says:

> [said] function is closed

Are there any updates on how to do this?

I was thinking perhaps with the URI Scheme it may be possible:

[How do I link to wechat from a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425553/how-do-i-link-to-wechat-from-a-webpage)